# Capacitor selection drives voltage fluctuation from TLV700 LDO

Tags: voltage, transistors, capacitor, voltage-regulator, ldo

I am building a wireless charger based on bq500212A ([datasheet here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXE1J.png))

However, I have an issue with the LDO: It fluctuates the voltage by about 400mV in a wave.

Blue is where I put my oscilloscope probe. Green is where I put the oscilloscope GND. Green squares represent the installed components.
[image]

Here are some oscilloscope images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Added AC coupling:
[image]

It's my first time using the oscilloscope for this purpose. This is what I could find on the internet. I also checked the 5V line and it does not present these fluctuations.

Could you tell me what am I doing wrong and why I don't get a stable 3V3 output?

Comment: As you want to design a Wireless charger, there will be lots of EMC Noise. You should use the SMD DSO probe, otherwise, it will pick lots of noise, which is happening with you. Follow the link "https://i2.wp.com/circuitcellar.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Figure-5-web.jpg?fit=456%2C212&ssl=1"

Comment: What is your source of power, please also check noise on the power input

Comment: As I said earlier, the 5V line was checked. No problems there. The 5V input comes from a Raspberry Pi 4B.

Comment: I can see that you are using the Enable pin, but I do not see what pulls to a high level when the LDO is enabled.

Comment: @csabahu I have hardwired the 5v line to the LDO for now. It's enabled. Also, I tested the SMD DSO probe (as suggested by Deepak) and I have the same result.

Comment: This is a bit strange for oscillation, but if it is, its frequency will change if you connect one in parallel with the output capacitor.

Comment: Hm... I'm afraid I am not connecting ANY capacitors whatsoever. All the components soldered right now are the LDO, an unconnected transistor (ignore) and a load (led+resistor). That's all.

Comment: The stability of the LDO requires a capacitor at its output. From what I see to the right of it, I thought it was a capacitor.

Comment: Thanks, csabahu. I have shown you the layout, but in reality, there is no capacitor soldered. I will solder on the capacitor and try again.

Comment: Use MLCC 1uf || 0.1uF at the LDO output, it should solve the problem.

Comment: Problem solved. Post it as an answer. I looked up the datasheet of the TLV700 and it's true indeed. I don't know why this took me so long to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seemed to be a problem with the value of the capacitor I was using after the LDO.

Below are some screenshots:

This is the LDO, using a ~4uF capacitor. Note the dips 300mV (which is HUUUGE)
[image]

And this is the LDO with the right 100nF, as pointed in the datasheet [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv700.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-digikeymode-df-pf-null-wwe&ts=1601904187103):
[image]

This is probably the clearest 3.3V source I have seen so far. Note how it sits within 10mV.

Comment: You worked a lot with the power supply, but I like that you even had to read the datasheet in the end. :)